# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #3](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/election/3) on Network Engineering has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Zac67]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/election/3) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5641813193916416).

Comment: Folks, thanks for your trust!

Comment: Congratulations and welcome onboard, @Zac67!

Comment: Welcome to the team, and good luck! You now have a target on your back, so grow some thick skin :)

Comment: Re: thick skin… moderators are really a free stack exchange janitorial service… your pay is a Unicode character and a yearly gold badge…

Answer (score 4):

Huge congratulations Zac67, it is no less than deserved. You have such great knowledge and good ways to explain your answers.

Thank you for taking the time to become a member of the mod team!

Comment: OMG!  He's back!

Comment: Yeah I come by from time to time :D